# Updated query showing old data in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I refresh my page to see my new updated data, it shows the old data.

When I refresh AGAIN it shows the new data.

How do I refresh one time and get new data?

1. Get data
2. Update data
3. Show updated data

All three steps in one refresh page, is that possible?

Here's what I use:

```
$curTime = time();
$endTime = $results->data[$i]['ends'];
$bannedid = $results->data[$i]['bid'];

if ($endTime < $curTime)
{                                                   
    $query = "UPDATE bans SET RemoveType='E' WHERE bid='$bannedid'";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($results->data[$i]['RemoveType'] == 'E')
    {
        $UnbannedReason = "(Expired)";
    }

    echo $UnbannedReason;
}
```

Comment: where do you 'get' data? where is `$UnbannedReason` set initially?

Comment: Sounds like a browsing caching issue.

Comment: If you use Ctrl+F5 to refresh do you have the same problem?

Comment: Ctrl+F5 has the same issue, and cache isn't the problem, just tested. I get data from my config.php which is not necessary because it's just NULL.

Comment: Once the endTime is less than curTime, it should change to 'E' from NULL and it should update in the echo that E = Expired with only one refresh, but I dont know how. I looked everywhere

Comment: just follow the simple logic of having the update up first, then show the selected row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix this, by adding this after the UPDATE query:

```
if ($_GET['reloaded'] != 1) {
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.php?reloaded=1\">";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use php header

```
header("Refresh:0");
```

Comment: When doing this, it refreshes the page infinite times?